# What all local variables goto Data/BSS segment?

Tags: c++, c, nm

The man page of `nm` here: [MAN NM](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html) says that

> The symbol type. At least the following types are used; others are, as
>   well, depending on the object file format. If lowercase, the symbol is
>   usually local; if uppercase, the symbol is global (external)

And underneath it has "b" and "B" for "uninitialized data section (known as BSS)" and "d" and "D" for "initialized data section"

But I thought local variables always goto Stack/Heap and not to "Data" or "BSS" sections. Then what local variables is nm talking about?

Comment: [Related post regarding where variables are allocated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798486/bss-segment-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"local" in this context means file scope.

That is:

```
static int local_data = 1; /* initialised local data */
static int local_bss; /* uninitialised local bss */
int global_data = 1; /* initialised global data */
int global_bss; /* uninitialised global bss */

void main (void)
{
   // Some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Function-scope static variables go in the data or BSS (or text) sections, depending on initialization:

```
void somefunc(void)
{
    static char array1[256] = "";            // Goes in BSS, probably
    static char array2[256] = "ABCDEF…XYZ";  // Goes in Data
    static const char string[] = "Kleptomanic Hypochondriac";
                                             // Goes in Text, probably
    …
}
```

Similar rules apply to variables defined at file scope, with or without the `static` storage class specifier — uninitialized or zero-initialized data goes in the BSS section; initialized data goes in the Data section; and constant data probably goes in the Text section.